# Alternatives to Structure add-on?

Tags: structure, pages, page-uri

I've been using Structure to build EE sites for a long time, but on my biggest site I've run into a recurring Structure bug that they can't seem to reproduce or fix and it looks like I'll have no choice but to redevelop parts of the site using an alternative add-on that's more stable for me needs.

For those interested, here's the catastrophic bug I've been encountering: https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/7616-all-entries-in-structure-managed-channel-suddenly-closed-and-all-structure-data-lost/page/1

So, is there a good alternative to Structure that would allow me to easily view managed pages in a nice Structure like page tree, and something that also provides per-page template selection and templategroup/template URL independence?

Answer (score 2):

I also use Structure for a long time but I'm now trying NavEE and I must say it looks great. I follow your problem with Structure for a while now and that's why i am looking for an alternative to Structure.

Comment: +1 for NavEE. In combination with the Pages module it gives me everything I could need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Structure mostly for navigation, Taxonomy can be of help: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/taxonomy

Answer (score 1):

Try the built in Pages module. The UI isn't quite the same as Structure but you can see a tree like layout of the site if you wish. In reality I've found that nobody has really  missed Structure's apparent convenience.

Answer (score 1):

We use a combination of Low Reorder and Categories to enable the client to easily place and manage entries where they want in the navigation structure.

In this fairly simple example we have the following fixed top level menu items.

Corporate / Investor Centre / Projects / Contact / Home

[image: Site showing navigation]

Corporate, Investor Center and Projects draw entries from the same channel.

We have corresponding categories attached to the channel - Corporate, Investor Center and Projects.

When the client creates or manages an entry they can check the relevant category, for example "Corporate".

[image: Editing entry and Categories]

Low Reorder is used so that there is a "set" for each menu item -  Corporate, Investor Center and Projects

[image: Low Reorder Sets]

Each Low Reorder set draws entries from the channel and filters them with entries that have been tagged with the relevant Category.

[image: Filtering the sets]

The client can happily reorder the entries and this is reflected on the front end.
It is also easy for them to have an entry appear under a different menu by simply checking a different category when they edit an entry.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this bug can't be replicated and we haven't experienced such issues with other customers. I wish there was a way for us to get this working for you.

Comment: <rant> Travis, that's a bit unfair as this bug has been around since 2010, which I remember reporting on numerous times, and there are loads of other instances on your support site, most of which are closed as it's near impossible to replicate so unknown if resolved.  There have been many versions released since then, but the issue is still consistent, with the same symptoms and the trigger is saving or deleting an entry. </rant>

Comment: Travis, don't get me wrong I completely sympathize with the impossible situation you are in of trying to fix a bug you can't reproduce. However, I've given as many clues as I can find about what the cause is and have stopped receiving any kind of response from your support forum on this issue, even though I've suggested possible alternative ways to bypass the most damaging parts of the bug. I don't see what choice I have but to move to something else if you can't fix the problem.

Comment: Travis, I just posted a comment on that tenderapp discussion asking for a little direction to help me figure this out. Would greatly appreciate a reply there when you can.

Comment: Not sure why I'm not getting notifications for this post. I had no idea anyone responded… Anyway, Peter, it has popped up and been fixed. Unfortunately, EE's SAEF and now Safecracker are not the most solid of features. There's only so much we can do and we always jump on it when a fix is required. It's honestly one of the features we've lost the most time and energy on over the history of Structure. The forums are full of dead ends, but we often don't hear back from people that either fix their own issue, figure things out themsleves or upgrade an dare fine.

Comment: I want to point out that this is ONLY related to entries through external fields, Structure does not have random data loss. This particular issue/ticket has custom code and a LOT of add-ons that are not typical to the average install as well.